# RelativeLayout toLeftOf

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout inside a LinearLayout which I use to display some data:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/uhr"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/time"
            android:src="@drawable/event_clock" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:autoLink="web|email"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that I want my ImageView to the left and the TextView right beside it.
If I however change `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/time"` to `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/time"` It only shows the TextView but the ImageView dissapears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the `layout_toRightOf` on the TextView then:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/uhr"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/uhr"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/event_clock" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wow ok strange enough that didn't work yesterday (always gave me errors and wouldn't compile) and today it works. Didn't change any code, same computer etc. Thanks alot for your help though!

Comment: THis "solution" works sometimes, sometimes it doesnt. I have a similar layout, but with two EditTexts and I want an image to the left of those EditTexts. It doesnt work with the "toLeftOf" on the image, but it works with the "toRightOf" if I set it on the first EditText. However, if I try the same thing, ie setting "toRightOf" on the second EditText, it has no effect - the second image isnt shown.

Comment: Are you sure it's not an issue of IDs being declared after you actually use them ? Make sure you always use the "@+id/..." notation all the time (not "@id/...")